# how to make automatic paginator in p:dataGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, paginator

I would like to make my `<p:dataGrid>` pagination automatic. Without using the next button, move to the next page in few seconds.

```
<p:dataGrid id="cars" var="of" value="#{infoBaseOfVals.listinfoBaseOf}"
    columns="2" rows="4" layout="grid" paginator="true" cellpadding="10" 
    cellspacing="20px" scrolling="false" responsive="true" type="unordered" itemType="none"  
    paginatorTemplate="Nombre OFs : #infoBaseOfVals.listinfoBaseOf.size()} OFs {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80">
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: JSF, results, on the client side, in all just plain html, css and javascript (as you can see in the answer). So next time look for 'generic' questions like 'how can I click on a button from javascript' or how can use the paginator js api... or...

Answer (score 2):

For recent versions of PrimeFaces (at least 6.0, but maybe also some before) You can achieve that with a little javascript. Set the widgetVar attribute to your dataGrid and add something like this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);

myDataGridPaginator = PF('myDatagridWidgetVar').getPaginator();

function myTimer() {
  myDataGridPaginator().setPage(myDataGridPaginator.cfg.page + 1);
}
```

For older PrimeFaces version (if this does not work) see the other answer

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of PrimeFaces it works with javaScript 
this is the script

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
function myTimer() {
    var myvar1 = myDataGrid.cfg.paginator.page;
    var myvar2 = myDataGrid.cfg.paginator.pageCount - 1;
    if(myvar1 == myvar2)
        myDataGrid.paginator.setPage(0) ;
    myDataGrid.paginator.setPage(myDataGrid.cfg.paginator.page + 1);
    }
```

```html
 <p:dataGrid widgetVar="myDataGrid" id="cars" var="of" value="#infoBaseOfVals.listinfoBaseOf}"
columns="2" rows="4"paginator="true" responsive="true" itemType="none"  
 paginatorTemplate="Nombre OFs : #{infoBaseOfVals.listinfoBaseOf.size()} OFs {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
 rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,8,16,24"  >
 <h:outputText value="#{of.of_id}" />
 </p:dataGrid>
```