# How to set auto next datagrid pagination on primefaces 6.2

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, datagrid

I've try this, but doesn't work.
[how to make automatic paginator in p:dataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828581/how-to-make-automatic-paginator-in-pdatagrid)

```
 <p:dataGrid var="serv" id="datagridID" widgetVar="datagridWid" value="#{telemetryServiceBacking.telGet}" columns="3" layout="grid"
         rows="6" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="Number of : #{telemetryServiceBacking.telGet.size()} 
         {CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
```

and this is my javascript

```
 <script>
        function timer(){
                        var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
                    }

                    function myTimer() {
                        var myvar1 = datagridWid.cfg.paginator.page;
                        var myvar2 = datagridWid.cfg.paginator.pageCount - 1;
                        if(myvar1 == myvar2){
                             PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().setPage(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().setPage(datagridWid.paginator.getCurrentPage() + 1);
                        }
                }
    window.onload = timer;
 </script>
```

the set page manual work perfectly, but I don't know how to get current page and total page in the `<p:datagrid>` with javascript

```
PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().setPage(1);
```

and, is there any documentation for new update primefaces?

Comment: So effectively, `var myvar1 = datagridWid.cfg.paginator.page;` does not work? Tried `PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().page`  or `PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().getPage()`?

Comment: See the link you referred to again. You used the wrong answer for modern PF versions. I improved the answers a little.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make automatic paginator in p:dataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828581/how-to-make-automatic-paginator-in-pdatagrid)

Comment: how do u get the documentation of changes PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().getPage()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here to get current page on PF 6.2

```
('datagridWid').getPaginator().page or PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().getPage()
```

Because I don't know the syntax to get current page yesterday, I use simple validation on backing bean.

```
    int maxList = 0; 
    int list = 23;
    pageIndex = list / 12; //12 means 12 data each page
    maxList = list % 12;
    if(maxList > 0) {
        pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
    }

    pageIndexString = pageIndex + ""; //convert to string
```

and on my xhtml :

```
<script>

                        var i = 0;
                        var pageIndexString = #{yourBackingBean.pageIndexString};
                        function timer(){
                            var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000); //means 5second
                        }

                        function myTimer() {
                            if(i != pageIndexString){
                                PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().setPage(i+1);
                                i++;
                            }
                            else if(i == pageIndexString){
                                PF('datagridWid').getPaginator().setPage(0);
                                i = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        window.onload = timer;
</script>
```